# JQuery UI Accordion Widget displays multiple icons

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm having trouble with the JQuery UI accordion widget. I can get the accordion working and the icons showing for a collapsed and expanded accordion, but I get all of the icons and not just the +/- icon.

When collapsed
[image]

When expanded
[image]

Here is my driver for the JQuery widget

```
$(function () {
    $('.accordion').accordion({
        "header" : "h3",
        "icons": {
            "header": "ui-icon-plus",
            "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minus"
        },
        "heightStyle": "content",
        "collapsible": true,
        "active": false,
    });
});
```

here is the HTML it is being called on

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3></h3><!--Left blank to show all the icons showing-->
    <div>
        <p>This is sample Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JQuery-UI zip file I downloaded came with 6 files that contained all of the various icons available and it appears like the whole row is showing and gets shifted to the left to hide some icons when the accordion is either expanded or collapsed. Do I have to use the theme roller to roll my own theme and only get the icons I want or if there some height/width/offset settings I need to specify in the driver. I've tried to follow the documentation but it's not been exceedingly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a css collision between the JQuery UI css

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

and some css I was using for other parts of the site

```
.content span {
    color : #B47000;
    font-size : 1.25em;
    width : 100%;
}
```

Since the `<div class="accordion">` was nested within `<div class="content">` the css for `.content span` was overriding the `.ui-icon` css because JQuery UI inserts `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus">` inside the header element to hold the icon.

I changed my css to be more exclusive and that resolved this problem.

```
/*Adding > fixed the error*/
.content > span {
    color : #B47000;
    font-size : 1.25em;
    width : 100%;
}
```